# This is my first time using nodejs, I am getting the following error while running npm run start command

Tags: node.js, reactjs

'env-cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm verb lifecycle frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\nobu\frontend-ibb-dashboard\node_modules.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm verb lifecycle frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3~start: CWD: C:\nobu\frontend-ibb-dashboard
npm info lifecycle frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3~start: Failed to exec start script
npm verb stack Error: frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3 start: `env-cmd -f ./env/local.env react-app-rewired start`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
npm verb pkgid frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3
npm verb cwd C:\nobu\frontend-ibb-dashboard
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm verb argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm verb node v14.17.3
npm verb npm  v6.14.13
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3 start: `env-cmd -f ./env/local.env react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend-ibb-dashboard@2.0.8-dev.3 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm timing npm Completed in 1030ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-15T06_58_17_815Z-debug.log

i tried delete node_module and try again npm install but nothing happened

Comment: Obviously, npm cannot find the `env-cmd` package. You must install it, using `npm i env-cmd` or globally using `npm i -g env-cmd`. Package Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd